# path too long_truncated at 1024 characters_path cannot be edited

Tags: windows, octave

I am kinda stuck here, trying to add octave to my path, which is too long (1024 characters is the maximum). I tried to modify it manually going to Advanced system settings, but after I modify the path, the changes I make are not saved (not even if I restart). I tried to modify the path also using Rapid Environment Editor and PowerShell, but nothing. Please, could anyone give me a further advice on how to solve the problem? My IT skills are not advanced at all and at the moment I really do not have a clue on how to proceed. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is too long, you'll have to remove some other directories from your path before adding the Octave directory.

Comment: Hi Cate, I have a feeling you may be asking the wrong question ... what are you trying to do exactly? There isn't really a need to have octave in the path in a windows environment, although you obviously could if you wanted to. Also, are you running on a university environment (i.e. networked profile etc?). Are you sure you have the necessary admin permissions to change such variables?

Comment: Hi Tasos, thank you very much for your comment. I managed to solve the issue by modifying my path. I needed Octave in the path to be able to read some matlab code in python :)